# Hadoop: Namenode does not start. JPS Shows only DataNode to be running

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop

I'm building a hadoop cluster with two Ubuntu boxes. I have a dedicated Hadoop user on each machine called "hduser". When I use "start-dfs.sh" on the master, the DataNode is created on both the master and the slave. But the NameNode is not created on the master. Even when I ask the daemon to specifically start NameNode, it doesn't work.

```
hduser@hbase1:~$ bash /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh start namenode
starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-namenode-hbase1.out
hduser@hbase1:~$ jps
20992 Jps
19492 DataNode
```

The log file contains this:

```
2013-12-31 14:45:52,585 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode:
Exception in namenode join
java.net.BindException: Port in use: 0.0.0.0:50070
at org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer.openListener(HttpServer.java:742)
at org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer.start(HttpServer.java:686)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeHttpServer.
start(NameNodeHttpServer.java:153)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.startHttpServer(NameNode.java:626)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:488)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:684)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:669)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1254)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1320)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:174)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:139)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:77)
at org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector.open(SelectChannelConnector.java:216)
at org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer.openListener(HttpServer.java:738)
... 8 more
2013-12-31 14:45:52,588 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1
2013-12-31 14:45:52,591 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode:SHUTDOWN_MSG:
```

Comment: You already have something bound to port 50070.  The namenode uses that port for its http interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your port 50070 is occupied by some other service.

http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP1/HDP-Win-1.3.0/bk_installing_hdp_for_windows/content/win-troubleshoot-2-2.html

You can change your web interface port settings in core-site.xml to some other port than 50070:

```
<property>
    <name>dfs.http.address</name>
    <value>50070</value>
</property>
```

Comment: Excellent solution. My problem got resolved. Thanks a lot. Mine was on Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some config related issue to me. Have you specified 50070 as the port to be used by NN in your core-site.xml?50070 is the port used by the HDFS web ui. Also, it should not try to bind on 0.0.0.0. Could you please show me your config files??